# How to create dialog with EditText and DatePicker

Tags: android, dialog, datepicker, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to make a Dialog with EditText and a DatePicker.
Unfortunately, I can't customize the DatePickerDialog and the XML DatePicker is horrible (it shows a little calendar and I don't need it).

My current custom dialog is:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:hint="Title" />
<DatePicker 
    android:id="@+id/ad_date_picker"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
```

Can someone explain me how can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: If you read the [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) documentation, you'll see there is a property called `android:calendarViewShown` that controls whether the calendar is shown or not